# package theoremref

Tags: compilation-error

When I compiled my tex file, every code concerning \thref and \thlabelgot problem, showing error message like 
"...{{@currentlabel}{thmref@currname}{\expandafter\strip@peri...1.371...{theorem}\thlabel{thm: production}"

However, if I type "R" to "run without stopping", then (for example) "Theorem" of "Theorem 2.6" disappears and only "2.6" is shown.

Any reference, suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: However, I use a .STY file and it contains a long code, and thus it is not convenient to post here. Is there is another way to explain my problem in more details?

Comment: Using `cleveref` is safer.